# What's wrong with my code ? everytime I click the app crashes

Tags: android, calculator

I'm working on a simple calculator
I'm still a beginner and don't know much about java or android
however, everytime  I click on the button the app crashes!
what's wrong with the code ?

```
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
final EditText ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET);
final EditText ET2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET2);
final EditText ET3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET3);
final TextView TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
final TextView TV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {


                String et = ET.getText().toString();
                String et2 = ET2.getText().toString();
                String et3 = ET3.getText().toString();

                for (int i = Integer.parseInt(et2); i < Integer.parseInt(et3); i++) {

    try {           
        str = et.replace("X", "" + i);
                    } 
         catch (Exception e) {
                        str = et.replace("x", "" + i);
                    }

                    int rslt = Integer.parseInt(str);
                    TV.append( " " + i )
                    TV2.append( " " + rslt )

                }
            }
        }

    });
```

That's all codes already
this code is meant to make a table for a F(X) method like the one on the casio calculator. I may need it for school
like :
F(X) = X^2 + X*4 - 3

Comment: Please post your log and more code of your activity

Comment: Check `adb logcat` output and put stack trace here.

Comment: Your new code is not compiling, so it cannot crash at all...

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that outer `try` misses corresponding `catch` block and you do not check whether proper number is entered in Et2 and Et3. Integer.parseInt will throw an exception if provided text is not a proper number.

Comment: I forgot to remove the outer try because I removed the outer catch
I removed it because it was meaningless I just wanted to know where the problem was

Comment: I tried
    try {
                            int rslt = Integer.parseInt(et.replace("X", ""+i));
                            TV.append(" " + i);
                            TV2.append(" " + rslt);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            int rslt = Integer.parseInt(et.replace("x", ""+i));
                            TV.append(" " + i);
                            TV2.append(" " + rslt);
                        }
it gave the same error
the error is because sums like : X + 2 ( X will be changed to i ) isn't provided as integer
What should I do ?

Comment: Now your code may throw an exception from `catch` clause. I think you should become familiar with logcat and debugger to collect more information. You could easily spot the error and ask more specific questions.